# Meteor Windows 10 Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink ...dev_bundle

Tags: node.js, windows, meteor

I just installed `meteor` on my Windows 10 system and tried to start an existing Meteor project by running `meteor` in the root of the project directory.

This gives an error

```
C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:190
      throw error;
      ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\test\test-meteor-project\.meteor\local\dev_bundle'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.unlinkSync (fs.js:932:18)
    at exports.makeLink (C:\tools\cli\dev-bundle-links.js:20:8)
    at [object Object].ensureDevBundleLink (C:\tools\project-context.js:1444:7)
    at [object Object]._readFile (C:\tools\project-context.js:1378:10)
    at new exports.ReleaseFile (C:\tools\project-context.js:1328:8)
    at C:\tools\cli\main.js:869:22
```

Running `meteor reset` gives the same error! What can we do to solve this?

Comment: It might be a file permission error, unlink is the Unix equivalent of delete. Try deleting C:\Users\test\test-meteor-project\.meteor\local and try again

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who stumbles across this same issue.

The problem I had was that in the directory where I was tyring to create a new meteor project, there already existed a  `.meteor` folder. (Probably from an earlier failed attempt).

E.g. In the folder Meteor I was trying to create meteor project three

```
-Meteor
--.meteor
--project one
--project two
```

The solution was simply to delete the  `.meteor` folder.

Another thing to try is running the cmd window with admin rights.

I've written up this and other Meteor fixes here:
http://blacksandsolutions.azurewebsites.net/blog/meteorjs-on-windows-10-2/

Comment: Deleting the whole `.meteor` folder fill make meteor commands throw a "Not in a Meteor project". It works deleting only `.meteor/local` folder.

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting your yourApp.meteor\local folder

Comment: This helps. I work on several very similar Meteor webapps and when I need to create a new one I just copy over the entire project dir. I guess this messes up the linking. Deleting `local` helps. It just gets recreated on next `meteor` run.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem just make a symbolic link.
If someone has this problem, just make a symbolic link dev_bundle in '.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle'

I think that this is the problem your dev_bundle in meteor project unlink to dev_bundle